My liferay remote services did not appear in /api/jsonws (JSON Web Service)
I develop a custom service with service-builder in liferay workspace dxp-7.4-ga1, in the service.xml all my entities have the attribute remote-service to "true". I use spring as dependency injection mechanism and I deploy the bundles without issues.
I check with ds:unsatisfied if there are a depency issue but it's not the case.
But When I check /api/jsonws, my context Name did not appear
I'm using a dockerized Liferay dxp 7.4 2023.Q4.2
